# Wait for DAG thats triggered with TriggerDagRunOperator to finish using ExternalTaskSensor

Tags: airflow

I am currently using the `wait_for_completion=True` argument of the `TriggerDagRunOperator` to wait for the completion of a DAG. That is fine, except it hogs up a worker just for waiting.

I am thinking it's possible to wait async using `ExternalTaskSensor`?  However, I also read I need the execution date to be synchronised? What if I wanna wait for the instance of DAG run by TriggerDagRunOperator instead of just by time. Cos it's possible that there are many DAGs that run at about the same time? I am concerned it doesn't wait for the right one.

Also, if the DAG is triggered manually, the execution time is also not fixed?

Comment: Are we talking about 3 DAGs here? Is it possible to write down all DAGs and descriptions like DAG A has `TriggerDagRunOperator`, DAG B has `ExternalTaskSensor` and schedule or any relative config of all DAGs mentioned in here?  I cannot picture it well yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my understanding is correct, you want to have a dag which is triggered by TriggerDagRunOperator, not dag schedule time ?

set `schedule_interval = None` can remove dag run schedully.